# I need to sync a source windows folder to a destination with paths over 260 characters

Tags: backup, file-synchronization, long-paths

I wrote software to make a destination folder match a source folder, deleting extra files from the destination. Files with the same timestamp and size are skipped. It goes real fast and I use it for many purposes. What I also do is backup an entire windows C: drive by booting to a second partition. To do this a drive letter is mapped to a path for that machine on a shared folder, and because a drive letter is used the length of source and destination paths are the same. Unfortunately I cannot easily backup the drive containing all the backups. This is because many of the paths exceed the 260 character limit.

I would like to find software that doesn't have this limitation and functions similar to what is described here.

Comment: Take a look at the [syncback](http://www.2brightsparks.com/) line of software.  I think at least one of their products will do what you want.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer. The software works excellent. It's also free.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SyncBack Free](http://www.2brightsparks.com/download-syncbackfree.html) will do exactly what you want.

It will allow you to specify your source and destination folders, and skip files with the same timestamps.

Unlike some other programs, it supports long pathnames that exceed the 260 character limit.

It is closed-source, but free of charge.

Comment: Yes, it works nice! I'm amazed. For a sync job it even allows to specify external commands before and after the job, such as turning off a server engine. It does everything my software does, and more.